# iPhone Lockscreen Password style framework

Tags: iphone, xcode, lockscreen

Is there any framework like MessageUI (which has a mail composer) that has something like the lockscreen password style for cocoa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jslockscreen